# XML - How to get child node count using java

Tags: java, xml

I have a java code as given below. As per my understanding, it should display the number of child nodes of parent node `<parent>` in the given `test.xml` file.

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File("./test.xml"));
    System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("parent").item(0).getChildNodes().getLength());
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is my `test.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<parent> 
    <sid>hello</sid>
</parent>
```

Here in this XML the number of child nodes of the parent node `parent` is 1( ie, `<sid>hello</sid>`). But the above snippet outputs as 3. Can anybody please help me to figure out whats happening here? I am a newbie to java and I appreciate your help.

Comment: Examine the type of each node.  Not all child nodes are Element nodes.  I think you’ll find that there is only one child node which is of type Element.

Comment: why it outputs 3 instead of 1 ? is the snippet counting all nodes including `parent` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anybody please help me to figure out what's happening here?

Your node `parent` has indeed `3` child nodes:

1. A text node containing the characters between `<parent>` and `<sid>`
2. An element node corresponding to `<sid>hello</sid>`
3. A text node containing the characters between `</sid>` and `</parent>`

It is known as **mixed content**, it is the ability to mix text and elements inside a given element.

If you try to launch your program with `<parent><sid>hello</sid></parent>`, you will get `1` as you expect since you have no characters anymore outside the tags.

A good example of **mixed content** is `XHTML` where you can have something like

```
<p>Hello <strong>World</strong></p>
```

If you parse this, the element `p` will have `2` nodes as we expect one text node containing "`Hello`" and an element node `<strong>World</strong>`.

---

> how can we get the number child nodes(number of `sid` child nodes) ?

The easiest way is to use a [`JDOM`](http://www.jdom.org/) or [`dom4j`](http://dom4j.github.io/) parser instead as they are meant to be used to parse pure XML data structure which is what you need here.

**The code would then be in case of `JDOM`:**

```
SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
Document document = saxBuilder.build(new File("./test.xml"));
System.out.println(document.getRootElement().getChildren().size());
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

**The code would then be in case of `dom4j`:**

```
SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document document = reader.read(new File("./test.xml"));
System.out.println(document.selectNodes("/parent/*").size());
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

Comment: I have the same XML file and its concerned child nodes are(sid) dynamically creating ones. And it follows the same structure as given the question so that there will be those kind "hidden" text fields. So how can we get the number child nodes(number of `sid` child nodes) ?